# How to display label, input and image in a single line?

Tags: html, css

[image: this is screen shot when I am removing margin-left it's giving like this]

Hi in the below code I want to display label, image and input in a single line for that I used inline-block but it's not working. Now it's displaying one by one.

**html**

```
<div class="person_pic">
    <label>Please upload your photo</label>
    <input  type='file' name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.person_pic {
 margin-left: 201px;
display: inline-block;
font-weight:bold;
}
.person_pic label{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: I have a jsfiddle, but it seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/5qqf80bh/ - what is it that you're trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually, img, label and input, by default are put side by side.

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alboy51/ta6dr13h/)

```
<label>Please upload your photo</label>
<input  type='file' name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

It displays in a new line because you have a large margin. If you extend the page, it will be on the same line.

Removing the margin should solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Remove margin-left from this class,

```
.person_pic { 
display: inline-block;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<span class="person_pic">
<label>Please upload your photo</label>
<input  type='file' name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</span>

.person_pic {
    margin-left: 201px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Use span instead of div , as span is inline -block .

Answer (score 3):

Now define `white-space : nowarp;` in your `.person_pic` class

as like this .

if you don't want to be remove `margin-left`

```
.person_pic {
  margin-left: 201px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;  // define white-space: nowarap 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rbb2g9cv/)

Answer (score 0):

Define CSS following CSS

```
.column {  float: left; padding: 5px; }
.row::after {   content: "";  clear: both;  display: table; }
```

Then HTML Code

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <h5>User Pic</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img width="40px" height="50px" style="padding-bottom: 5px" src="./assets/images/camera.png" />
          </div>
          </div>
```